# Do we have any Microsoft graph API to check the tenant id is for public cloud or national cloud?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Do we have any Microsoft graph API to check the tenant id is for public cloud or national cloud?

I'm working on the Microsoft Graph API support for outlook integration in one of my projects.
Planning to support for all the clouds available from Azure.
Based on the response I can decide on the changes right URL for the public cloud as well as the national cloud.

It is really appreciated if someone can help me with understanding the above point.
Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Ramesha

Answer (score 0):

Once you have signed in a user, you can use the `iss` claim in the token to identify the Azure cloud instance.

Use the [issuer metadata](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize&api-version=1.1) to get a list of valid issuers across the cloud instances.

or if you want to perform a lookup based on tenantId.

You can check whether a tenant is in Azure global or a [National cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-national-cloud) by trying to fetch the tenant metadata

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[{tenantid}/{tenant domain}]/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

examples for a test tenant like contoso.com:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/6babcaad-604b-40ac-a9d7-9fd97c0b779f/.well-known/openid-configuration

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

For AAD USGov, the example looks like the following

```
https://https://login.microsoftonline.us/33e01921-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Reference:

[National Clouds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-national-cloud)

[Fetch the OpenID Connect metadata document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kalyan.
The given URL gives me the information about all the preferred networks I mean cloud information.
I would like to know the end URL to get the access token beforehand to make any call to outlook server via graph API.

Comment: here is the thought to achieve it.
First I will make a call some API based on the tenant id or domain name and based on the response I will decide the information about cloud provider like below.
US Government
Germany
China operated by 21Vianet
Global service

If I can differentiate cloud information, then I can make the right call to get the access token intern to call the Graph APIs for Azure public cloud as well as the national cloud dynamically.

Comment: Hi Kalyan,

Thank you for updating the ways to do it.
I don't have access to the above URL https://https://login.microsoftonline.us/33e01921-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d/.well-known/openid-configuration.
Could you please help us with the response of this get URL for better understanding.

Comment: The url has a made up tenant's guid. Replace it with an actual tenant id